# bootstrap tabs are working but data is not being show?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working with bootstrap, I want to add a twitter bootstrap tab, I have added jQuery and bootstrap-tabs.js

I have added the following script:

```
<script>
  $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  });
</script>
```

and I am using the following code to add the tabs :

```
<div class="span12" id="stafftabs" style="margin-bottom: 20px;display:none;">
 <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
   <a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
     <a href="#dropdown1" data-toggle="tab">@fat</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#dropdown2" data-toggle="tab">@mdo</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
   <p>Raw</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
   <p>Food</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dropdown1">
   <p>Etsy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dropdown2">
   <p>Trust</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am getting the tabs to working properly, but no data is being shown in the tabs,

please help me guys to go out from this problem ?

Comment: u have an extra closing div in your markup

Comment: Isn't it because of `display:none;` in your parent div? If not, can you recreate using jsfiddle?

Comment: Hey, everything is fine when I see it in jsfiddle but I am using Supr bootstrap theme, may be some conflictions are there, I am unable to resolve that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nY89/49/) working without using JS. Easy to codify, simpler and faster.

You only need to use `class="tabbable"`